# SQLite Titanium Syntax Error

Tags: sqlite, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

The following SQL code works fine in SQLite Manager and in other SQLite systems, however when I use it in Titanium I get an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected String." If my syntax is wrong, how should it be coded for Titanium?

```
    SELECT Date, Content
    FROM MYDATABASE
    WHERE strftime('%m%d', Date) = strftime('%m%d', date('now'))
```

Comment: How are you writing it in Titanium?

Comment: `var rs = db.execute('SELECT Date, Content FROM MYDATABASE WHERE strftime('%m%d', date) = strftime('%m%d', date('now'))
 ');`

Comment: Did you try with double quotes "Select ...."?

Comment: When I try it with double quotes as follows `var rs = db.execute("SELECT Date, Content FROM MYDATABASE WHERE strftime('%m%d', date) = strftime('%m%d', date('now'))
 ");` I get an "Uncaught syntaxError: Unexpected token illegal"

Comment: You ares selecting Date and passing date in strftime('%m%d', date), why?

Comment: I'm selecting Date because I want my output to list the date along with the Content.  In short, I'm trying to select data from an SQLite database where all of the content was published on one date regardless of the year it was published in. For example: every July 17th listed in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you call your table MYDATABASE?  Are you stepping through the debugger and confirming that `var rs = db.execute("SELECT Date, Content FROM MYDATABASE WHERE strftime('%m%d', date) = strftime('%m%d', date('now')) ");`

In my Titanium Mobile project I first defined the database:

```
var db = Ti.Database.open('myDb');
db.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [MYDATABASE](id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Date DATE, Content TEXT)');
db.close();
```

I then executed this code from a function call

```
var db = Ti.Database.open('myDb');
var myresult = db.execute("INSERT INTO MYDATABASE(Date, Content) VALUES (date('now'), '12345')");
myresult = db.execute("SELECT Date, Content FROM MYDATABASE WHERE strftime('%m%d', Date) = strftime('%m%s', date('now')) ");
Ti.API.info('myresult: ' + myresult.fieldByName('Content'));
```

This code returns myresult: 12345 in the debug window successfully for me.  You probably need to provide us with a significant part of the source code so we can see the flow of the code.  Giving us pieces isn't working.

Unfortunately, I had to test this from another computer and hopefully didn't make any errors re-typing it here"

Comment: I tried you example in a new project and it works. My main project must be corrupted. Question, how can I add 'localtime' to your example?

Comment: localtime as a field to the database example?  Or to capture the local time?  I would think date('now') would be the local time of the device the call is made on.  If my answer is correct for your question, please accept my answer as the answer for the question.

Comment: If I manually change the devices time to 10:55pm EST on July 17th and run the above SQL, it reports data from July 18th.

Comment: datetime('now','localtime') returned the time from the system clock for me.  It appears according to the documentation that datetime('now') returns UTC time according to this http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/readme_sqlite_tutorial.html

Comment: How do I add an event listener so that the table is updated when the window/tab is in focus? My Current code works for webViews but I am unsure as how to apply it to tableViews. `win.addEventListener('focus',function(e){webview.reload();});`