# Insert command error - Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

im new to Appcelerator Titanium. I have successfully created DB. when i tried to insert a record it shows an error,

```
[ERROR] Script Error = Error occurred calling next on a PLSqliteResultSet. 
SQLite error: 'constraint failed' for 'INSERT INTO test (t_Id, t_Name)
VALUES (1,"sam")')' at app.js (line 24).
```

my code is:

```
Ti.Database.install('myDB.sqlite','myDB'); 
var db = Ti.Database.open('myDB'); 
db.execute('INSERT INTO test (t_Id, t_Name) VALUES (1,"sam")');
```

Please help me!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do it like this.

```
db.execute('INSERT INTO credentials(username,password,token) VALUES(?,?,?)',username,password,token);
```

this is to add dynamic values. username password and token are variables here.

Comment: i used - 
db.execute('INSERT INTO test(t_Id, t_Name) VALUES(?,?)',1,"sam");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516419/sqlite-titanium-syntax-error?rq=1      check this